# where can I find information on sharepoint profile content editing?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

My company is converting to Microsoft Office 365 and I have been tasked with migrating a JAVA program I wrote to update employee profiles in a MySQL database (a list of their accomplishments and areas of proficiency) to update the same information on Office 365 Sharepoint profiles. I am used to dealing with UNIX favors and not as familiar with Microsoft. Does anyone have suggestions on where to read up on Sharepoint and how to update user content with an external program?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you or not. It is the msdn page for sharepoint 2013 profiles.
[Sharepoint 2013 Profiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163800.aspx)